# Plot a function which depends on itself

Tags: plotting, functions

How can I plot a stepwise function like `f[a, t] = 10 Exp[-0.1 Sin[t]]` for `a > t` and `f[a, t] = f[a, t - 1] Exp[-0.1 a]` for `a < t`? If you see, for `a < t`, the function `f[a, t]` dependes on a previous value of itself.

Answer (score 5):

Two defintions of f, one each side of a.

```
f[a_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] /; a > t := 10 Exp[-0.1 Sin[t]];
f[a_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] /; a <= t := f[a, t - 1] Exp[-0.1 a];
```

Plot it.

```
Plot[f[5, t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: @m_goldberg - Thanks, one day I will figure out how to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your question, what is "sent" etc. but try this for a starting point

```
Manipulate[Plot[Piecewise[{{1 + 3 a, a <= t}, {10 Exp[-0.1 a*20], a > t}}], {a, 0, 2}], {t, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: Sorry..the question was:How can I plot a stepwise function like f[a,t]= 10exp(-0.1sent) for a>t, f[a,t-1]exp(-0.1a) for a<t....if you see for a<t the function depends on the previous value of the function f[a,t].

Comment: Still don't understand.  You have "sent" in your code which you have not defined.

Comment: sorry I meant sin[t]..